# What questions should I ask some who has a photography hobby?

Tags: terminology, philosophy

I asked a friend of mine what hobbies they liked. One was photography. What impressive question can I go back with to make a conversation? I know nothing about photography

Comment: How to engage in conversation would be a question better fit for  https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com ...people love to talk about what's important to them. You don't need to know anything about photography. Simply be interested in learning what they're interested in.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on interpersonal.SE

Comment: I agree this is off topic. That said, I would ask the friend what photographers the like and get inspiration from (and why).

Answer (score 2):

If you know nothing about photography, you should not ask "impressive questions".  This can only backfire.

The obvious question is to ask what the photographs the person makes are about.

With regard to "impressive questions", this will likely end like the apocryphal story about Ernest Hemingway asking a photographer he admired "I just love your work.  What kind of camera do you use?" to which the photographer responded with "And I am a great fan of your writings.  What typewriter do you use?".

Comment: To be fair, many writers love to talk about their typewriters!

Comment: @mattdm I don't remember where I heard it, but "tools talk about their tools; artists talk about their art". I'm hesitant to bring that up, because I talk about cameras _a lot_. =)